# Preserve Core Data Between Development Distributions

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4.6

I have a development distribution of an app out on a couple of devices.

Turns out my export functionality causes a memory leak - meaning I can't get that screen to open without reinstalling the distribution of the app.

Is that data totally lost? I'd really like to be able to save it.

Some ideas:

- Write a second helper app that could grab the data
- Write some sort of shell script that could retrieve the data plugged into a comptuer
- Plug in the devices to a computer... do something in Xcode... no lost data?

Is there any hope?

**UPDATE**

There was hope!

First - Your data is accessible via Organizer in XCode.

Second - New versions in iTunes do not overwrite core data. BUT you're going to want to make sure the version # increases as iTunes was somewhat finicky about sending over the new version. Your testers might be tempted to delete the app - replacing it in iTunes and re-syncing is all they need to do.

Comment: `•Plug in the devices to a computer... do something in Xcode... no lost data?` - You can use the Organizer to pull your files off of the device, so even if you have to re-deploy you should be able to get the data

Comment: Thanks @Turch - I hadn't seen that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the app without deleting it first, the data is not removed by the OS. So the new version of your app has the opportunity to read the old data.

Comment: From iTunes? I see it getting removed.

Comment: Are you sure? I think the data still should remain even when updating from iTunes (by dragging and dropping the new app bundle to iTunes when the old one is still there).

Comment: So to add more detail onto this - it looks like it's important to bump up your version number when creating a packet for distribution.